# Put "Show Deleted Comments" option into mod menu even if none exist

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

Currently, the option to show deleted comments only appears in the mod menu of a question if deleted comments exist.

This makes SOME sense, but I think the UX would be improved by leaving it in the menu but grayed out as disabled (like flag history is now).

[image]

Having the list of options change dynamically based on criteria which are, by definition, invisible can be confusing.

Additionally, any other options (like purge comments) should probably also always be shown, and just activated if the context allows it.

Comment: See also [Don't hide or disable menu options?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12756/dont-hide-or-disable-menu-items/12761#12761) /shameless plug

Comment: Also, for those curious as to the hidden options are: [sekrit tools](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bePUo.png)